# Is it possible to start a native executable from android native layer?

Tags: java, android, c++, android-studio, android-native-library

I have two "test" native executables and I'm trying to execute/start them as from native callback method.
This is how "test" applications look:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){
__android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "OHM", "INDEPENDENT PROCESS STARTED");
    while(1){
        usleep(1000000);
        __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "OHM", "INDEPENDENT PROCESS LOG");
    }
    return 1;
}
```

I've checked the appName.apk file and they are indeed part of the application (placed in the **assets/bin** folder when unpacked).
This is how I'm currently fetching assets related to the executable files:

```
void OSM::startSystem(AAssetManager* assetMngr){
     m_OhmTest = AAssetManager_open(assetMngr, "bin/ohm", AASSET_MODE_UNKNOWN);
     m_OmbTest = AAssetManager_open(assetMngr, "bin/omb", AASSET_MODE_UNKNOWN);
     __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "ASSETS", "LOADED");
     if(m_AppFinished){
         m_RunApp = true;
         m_AppFinished = false;
         pthread_create(&m_Thread, NULL, thread_adapter_OSM, (void*)this);
     }
}
```

Is it possible to somehow use the fetched assets (**m_OhmTest** and **m_OmbTest**) to run the executable?

Comment: Well, you already know the filename of each executable, why not just run them with `(std::)system()`?

Comment: Well even though I know the path to the executable in assets, I cannot start just by using that path because everything that is provided as assets is compressed together with the rest of the *_.apk_*.